# Make chat sheet from one element to another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>
        <notice>100</notice>
        <chat>10, 20, 30, 40</chat>
    </a>
    <a>
        <notice>101</notice>
        <chat>40, 50, 60</chat>
    </a>
    <a>
        <notice>102</notice>
        <chat>10, 30, 60</chat>
    </a>
    <a>
        <notice>103</notice>
        <chat>70, 10, 20</chat>
    </a>
</root>
```

My requirement is make a chat entry and find the effected notice like below example:

```
    <a>
    <chat>10</chat>
    <notice>100, 102, 103</notice>    
</a>

<a>
    <chat>20</chat>
    <notice>100, 103</notice>    
</a>

<a>
    <chat>30</chat>
    <notice>100, 102</notice>    
</a>
```

**Note: I have to use 1.0 version of XSLT.**

Comment: Why are chat 40, 50, 60 and 70 missing from your output? Also, which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using?

Comment: I want distinct chat# along with its affected notice#; I just showed the example hence these 40, 50 etc. were missing. I need this logic to be implemented in 1.0 version XSLT; saxon processor

Comment: If you are using Saxon, why are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Here is application dependency. Our application support only 1.0. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Is the processor included in the application? If so, which processor (vendor and version) is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly limited to XSLT 1.0, you will have to do this in three steps:

1. **Tokenize** the `chat` values. Ideally, at the end of this step you
   would have a variable containing:

   ```
   <item notice="100" chat="10"/>
   <item notice="100" chat="20"/>
   <item notice="100" chat="30"/>
   <item notice="100" chat="40"/>
   <item notice="101" chat="40"/>
   <item notice="101" chat="50"/>
   <item notice="101" chat="60"/>
   <item notice="102" chat="10"/>
   <item notice="102" chat="30"/>
   <item notice="102" chat="60"/>
   <item notice="103" chat="70"/>
   <item notice="103" chat="10"/>
   <item notice="103" chat="20"/>
   ```
2. Convert the variable into a **node-set**, using the EXSLT [`exsl:node-set()`](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) function (or another similar function supported by
   your processor).
3. **Group** the items by the `chat` attribute, using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

There are plenty of examples here showing how to do each step. If you run into problems, post a *specific* question.

Note that some XSLT processors support some extension functions that could be helpful here - notably: [`str:tokenize()`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) and [`set:distinct()`](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html).