# Using XSLT 1.0, sibling elements transformed as html table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've to transform two sibling elements content as an html table. First element contains "Journal-ID" and second element contains "Article-ID"

Example Input:

```
<root>
<journal-article>
    <journal>ARJ</journal>
    <article>10,12,14,18</article>
</journal-article>
<journal-article>
    <journal>BMJ</journal>
    <article>10,13,15,18</article>
</journal-article>
<journal-article>
    <journal>CAT</journal>
    <article>13,22,14,28</article>
</journal-article>
```

This must be transformed to

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Article</td>
    <td>Journals Affected</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>ARJ,BMJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>ARJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>BMJ,CAT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>ARJ,CAT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>BMJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>ARJ,BMJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>CAT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>CAT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please note that application supports only XSLT 1.0 version

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44111165/3016153

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT 1.0 to iterate over several XML elements with comma delimited values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560665/xslt-1-0-to-iterate-over-several-xml-elements-with-comma-delimited-values)